# Phantom line display in Visual Studio Code IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code I have a tab with a plain text file I use for scratch while working during the day. I place all kinds code, questions, TODO lists, etc in this file and will reference it from time to time. It's helpful for history purposes.

At any rate, this file has ballooned up to well over 46,000 lines over the years and I'm now seeing this odd phantom line being injected at my cursor. I am unable to select it or remove it. I thought it was being displayed as VS Codes way of letting me know that a software update was available but when checking that was not the case. This is what it phantom line looks like, it seems to contain a history of CSS classes used over the years which is odd.

[image: Phantom Line]

If I restart VS Code it goes away for a little while but then reappears. I have a feeling it might be because of the number of lines or perhaps memory but can't say for certain.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? I've probably enabled some setting by mistake and have no idea how to disable it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary.  Do you mean the dim grey lines that go across the screen on line 46154? That is just showing you what line you have your cursor on.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the HTML End Tag Labels plugin that was trying to auto complete some HTML that was somewhere within the 46k lines.

I would have thought by identifying the file as type Plain Text, the plug-in would ignore trying to close HTML tags (since its not an HTML file) but alas that's not the case.

Thank you Mark Ahrens for the tip!